# How to convert date format in nodejs using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document like this

```
{
            "_id": "5c2326cb5d558f6693577119",
            "date": "08/02/16 00:00",
            "symbol": "WLTW",
            "open": "113.300003",
            "close": 111.160004,
            "low": 110.459999,
            "high": 113.300003,
            "volume": 1200500,
            "createdAt": "2018-12-26T06:59:23.901Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-12-26T06:59:23.901Z"
        }
```

I am doing a query something like this

```
const getStockBySymbol = (data) => {
    console.log('Hitting Stock Model fine!!')
    return Stock.find({symbol: data})
        .then((stocks) => {
            console.log(stocks)
            if (stocks) { return stocks }
        })
}
```

I need to convert the `date` format to `Year-month-date` format

So current format is `dd\mm\yy` in `date` property I want to convert that to `yyyy-mm-dd`

I am new with MongoDB would be great if anyone could help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse string to ISODate using [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html) operator. The problem is that all formats for year expect four digits so it will parse your year to `0016` instead of expected `2016`. To fix that you can use [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/index.html) and [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) and manually add `2000`. Then you can use [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html) to convert it to your format, try:

```
Stockdb.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { symbol: "WLTW" }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            date: {
                $dateToParts: {
                    date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$date", format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" } }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            date: {
                $dateToString: {
                    date: {
                        $dateFromParts: {
                            day: "$date.day",
                            month: "$date.month",
                            year: { $add: [ 2000, "$date.year" ] }
                        }
                    },
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) overwrites existing fields in this case

EDIT: for lower MongoDB versions you can use [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operators assuming your `date` has fixed length:

```
Stockdb.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { symbol: "WLTW" }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            date: {
                $concat: [
                    '20',
                    { $substr: [ "$date", 6, 2 ] },
                    '-',
                    { $substr: [ "$date", 3, 2 ] },
                    '-',
                    { $substr: [ "$date", 0, 2 ] },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: actually i need to formate the date column not created and updated at

Comment: @Vikram sorry, modified my answer

Comment: another issue  is I am getting ```Unrecognized argument to $dateFromString: format``` which perhaps means I have mongo version less than 3.6 or something like that, WHat will I have to change in the above code

Comment: @Vikram modified my answer

Comment: now its working only for the about document but if I call my api again , the dates are converting like this ```201--0--20```

Answer (score 1):

you need to map results after fetching your data :

```
const getStockBySymbol = (data) => {
    return Stock.find({symbol: data})
        .then((stocks) => {
            if (stocks) { 
            var newStocks=stocks.map(function(stock){
             let formattedDate=moment(stock.date,"dd/mm/YY hh:mm").format("YYYY-mm-dd");
             stock.date=formattedDate;
             return stock;
            });
            return newStocks;
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're best option here would be to use momentjs library. It's a no-brainer solution for time format conversion :

```
moment(new Date(date)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

This should yield '2016-08-02'.

Comment: the date format is not an ISO so will it work fine with that ?

Comment: Can you also explain me how I can implement in the Mongodb query ?

Comment: As long as the Javascript Date() constructor can handle the date it is ok since the moment() constructor new a valid Date() object. In your case, the date is recognized. Your question is not clear in respect with want (and why) you want to achieve with mongoose. Do you want to query given a specific date ? Don't you want to just convert the date you received from Mongoose ? You can check Mongoose schema.post('find', function(result) { ..}) construct and set the momentjs trick there.

Comment: I just updated my question, so I have a component which accpet the formate I mentioned

Comment: Another suggestion using aggregate looked very nice as well, but can't see it anymore (?)